# How to parse this XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, feed

I want to parse xml feeds from Baidu(DB2312 encoded) http://news.baidu.com/n?cmd=1&class=civilnews&tn=rss

I always get error

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 8
```

If I change the xml to google feeds http://news.google.com/news?cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=b&output=rss, it works. Any suggestions?

```
def get_feeds():
        import sys
        import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
        from urllib import urlopen
        URL = "http://news.baidu.com/n?cmd=1&class=civilnews&tn=rss"
        #URL = "http://news.google.com/news?cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=b&output=rss"
        tree = etree.parse(urlopen(URL))

if __name__ == '__main__':
        get_feeds()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the excellent [`feedparser` library](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/), it has no problems parsing that URL:

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> feed = feedparser.parse('http://news.baidu.com/n?cmd=1&class=civilnews&tn=rss')
>>> print feed['feed']['title']
百度国内焦点新闻
>>> len(feed['entries'])
20
>>> print feed['entries'][0]['title']
强台风“天兔”正逐渐接近台湾陆地
```